# Sorting the various terms for "everywhere"

Tags: выбор-слова

I thought I had learned the word for *everywhere* some time ago—**всюду.** But this morning I ran across **везде,** which got me looking around, and so I also found **повсюду** and **повсеместно.**

What, if anything, are the distinctions in meaning among these words?

Also, are they all used fairly frequently, or are some of them uncommon in typical communication?

(I did also see *куда ни кинь,* but that one seems pretty easy to think of as *wherever you look.* So I get that distinction.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Везде** is the neutral word.

**Всюду** is just a bit archaic-sounding, but is otherwise equivalent.

**Повсюду** also answers “куда?” (in addition to “где?”), so with words like “разлететься” you can use повсюду but not the other synonyms mentioned.

**Повсеместно** literally means “in all places”, is somewhat formal and might feel a bit more figurative than literal (like “in most places, those that really matter”).

But in general these are near-perfect synonyms.

Comment: Thank you, that's a perfect answer. I'm a little surprised, though, that only повсюду (and not всюду) can be used to answer "куда?"

Comment: @spoko **разлетаться всюду** would have an unertone of several identical events happening at different places independently, and not one event  spreading out to several places from a single source

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка That's intriguing. :) I wonder if I understand why: Is it because the *по-* gives a sense of directionality, so that the spreading would seem to come from a single source?

Comment: @spoko often verbs of spreading motion are accompanied with the preposition **по**, **разъехаться по стране**, **рассредоточиться по полю**, **растекаться по земле**, **разбегаться по углам**, so this might be where it comes from, and i believe originally **повсюду** was two words **по всюду**, because it conforms to the same case paradigm as the above mentioned **по стране**, **по полю**

Answer (score 1):

I believe the words `(по-)всюду`, `повсеместно` and `везде` are completely interchangeable in respect to their meaning.
Despite that the words `всюду`, `повсюду`, `повсеместно` are a bit less frequently used nowadays, they don't sound ancient or too bookish. You can use them freely.

*Side note. The word `повсеместно` derived from the word `повсеместный` (`ubiquitous`).*

Comment: `Side note. The word повсеместно derived from the word повсеместный (ubiquitous).` Makes sense. Actually, all four of these words are pretty easy to parse, etymologically. But повсеместно especially -- it pretty much breaks apart into the phrase "in all places."